# VS2010 pdb lock error when modifying a css file

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, webserver

In one of my VS projects I get this error when I modify a css file in a App_Themes catalog in runtime.

> CS0042: Unexpected error creating debug information file '[..]\Temporary ASP.NET Files[..]\App_Theme_MySite.pdb: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I've used the Process Explorer and concluded that the file is being locked by the devenv.exe file.

In order to proceed I have to restart the entire project. 
It only happens in this one project and I have been unable to find what differs from other projects where I don't have this problem.

Solution running, css modification, solution crashes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'd similar issue.

Just remove the attribute or change it false.

```
<!--web.config --><configuration><system.web><compilation optimizeCompilations="false"
```

Found solution too....after 6-8 hours...